# hadoop: In which format data is stored in HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

I am loading data into HDFS using spark. How is the data stored in HDFS? Is it encrypt mode? Is it possible to crack the HDFS data? how about Security for existing data?

I want to know the details how the system behaves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDFS is a distributed file system which supports various formats like plain text format csv, tsv files. Other formats like parquet, orc, Json etc..

While saving the data in HDFS in spark you need to specify the format.

You can’t read parquet files without any parquet tools but spark can read it.

The security of HDFS is governed by Kerberos authentication. You need to set up the authentication explicitly.

But the default format of spark to read and write data is - parquet

Answer (score 1):

HDFS can store data in many formats and Spark has the ability to read it (csv, json, parquet etc). While writing back specify the format that you wish to save the file in.

reading some stuff on the below commands will help you this thing:

hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse

hadoop fs -get (this till get the files from hdfs to your local file system)

hadoop fs -put (this will put the files from your local file system to hdfs)